# Testing ActiveRecord against multiple databases in Travis (without dummy rails apps)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord, travis-ci

I'm currently working on getting the `activerecord_any_of` library set up to use TravisCI for automated testing across multiple database types.

Currently I have the following:

In `.travis.yml`

```
language: ruby
script:
  - bundle exec rake test
before_script:
  - mysql -e 'create database activerecord_any_of_test;'
  - psql -c 'create database activerecord_any_of_test;' -U postgres
before_install:
  - gem install bundler # use the latest bundler, since Travis doesn't update for us
rvm:
  - 1.9.3
  - 2.0.0
  - 2.1.1
  - rbx
  - jruby-19mode
env:
  - DB=mysql
  - DB=sqlite3
  - DB=sqlite3mem
  - DB=postgresql
gemfile:
  - gemfiles/rails3.gemfile
  - gemfiles/rails4.gemfile
  - gemfiles/rails_edge.gemfile
matrix:
  allow_failures:
    - gemfile: gemfiles/rails_edge.gemfile
    - env: DB=postgresql
    - env: DB=mysql
```

And `database.yml`:

```
sqlite3:
  adapter: <%= "jdbc" if defined? JRUBY_VERSION %>sqlite3
  database: activerecord_any_of.sqlite3.db
sqlite3mem:
  adapter: <%= "jdbc" if defined? JRUBY_VERSION %>sqlite3
  database: ":memory:"
postgresql:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: activerecord_any_of_test
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password:
  min_messages: warning
mysql:
  adapter: <%= defined?(JRUBY_VERSION) ? "jdbcmysql" : "mysql2" %>
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password:
  database: activerecord_any_of_test
  encoding: utf8
## Add DB Configuration to run Oracle tests
oracle:
  adapter: oracle_enhanced
  host: localhost
  username: activerecord_any_of_dev
  password:
  database: xe
```

And my `test_helper.rb`

```
plugin_test_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)

require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'

require 'rails'
require 'active_record'
require 'activerecord_any_of'

require "rails/test_help"
require 'combustion/database'
require 'database_cleaner'

require 'pry'
require 'logger'
require 'yaml'
require 'erb'

require 'support/models'

ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(plugin_test_dir + "/debug.log")

ActiveRecord::Base.configurations = YAML::load(ERB.new(IO.read(plugin_test_dir + "/db/database.yml")).result)
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(ENV["DB"] ||= "sqlite3mem")
ActiveRecord::Migration.verbose = false

Combustion::Database.create_database(ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[ENV["DB"]])
load(File.join(plugin_test_dir, "db", "schema.rb"))

ActiveSupport::TestCase.fixture_path = "#{plugin_test_dir}/fixtures"
ActiveSupport::TestCase.use_transactional_fixtures = true
ActiveSupport::TestCase.teardown do
  unless /sqlite/ === ENV['DB']
    Combustion::Database.drop_database(ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[ENV['DB']])
  end
end
```

When I run the tests on TravisCI, I get `sqlite` and `sqlitemem` matrices running just fine in most cases. However, when running against MySQL, I get the following errors:

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown database activerecord_any_of_test
```

And when running against PostgreSQL I get the error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::ConnectionBad: connection is closed: ROLLBACK
```

Since I'm creating the databases, I don't see why there would be any problems. As far as I can tell, I've configured the `database.yml` to use the proper credentials. Maybe I'm using `Combustion::Database` wrong? How can I properly connect to my databases in my tests?

I've adapted the setup used in [awesome_nested_set](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set) for setting up the tests for [activerecord_any_of](https://github.com/shekibobo/activerecord_any_of/tree/travis-setup). [Failing tests](https://travis-ci.org/shekibobo/activerecord_any_of) can be seen on Travis.